# Multiple test APKs

Tags: android, testing, firebase, apk, firebase-test-lab

Can I provide multiple test APKs using `--test` flag when I run tests using this command?

```
    gcloud firebase test android run \
  --type instrumentation \
  --app app-debug-unaligned.apk \
  --test app-debug-test-unaligned.apk \
  --device model=Nexus6,version=21,locale=en,orientation=portrait  \
  --device model=Nexus7,version=19,locale=fr,orientation=landscape
```

If not, is there any way to merge the test APKs so I do not have to run this command twice for two different test APK files?

Comment: I believe you can only provide one.

Comment: @DougStevenson I thought so.